# Quitar carácter "/" en fechas en un procedimiento almacenado

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo un procedimiento almacenado y en las fechas las guarda con el caracterer `/` deseo retirarlo para que solo me quede los números, por ejemplo, en lugar de `07/05/2017` debe de quedar `07052017`.

¿Hay alguna forma de retirar los caracteres?

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de dato es el campo donde se están guardando las `/`?

Comment: el tipo de datos es date, pero si lo necesito con este formato, pero lo que necesito es que despues de hacer las consultas, poder hacer un tipo explode para luego tomar la variable de fecha y concatenarlo con el nombre del archivo que se va a descargar a excel, pero si lo dejo con ese formato 01/02/1989 me genera error al ejecutarlo.

Comment: con que lenguaje de programacion estas trabajando?

Comment: Es decir, ¿quieres hacerlo en php o en mysql? ¿O en algún otro lenguaje?

Comment: es para hacer en mysql. el procedimiento almacenado se ejecutara en background

Answer (score 2):

Tienes un dato del tipo DATE por lo tanto no puedes quitarle un caracter y devolverlo como tal.

Lo que debes hace es convertirlo en string, dandole un formato y luego aplicar `REPLACE`

```
SELECT REPLACE(DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%d/%m/%Y'), '/', '') FROM tu_tabla
```

Answer (score 0):

En tu comentario mencionas que es un tipo de dato `DATE`, así se guardará en ese formato, pero si lo que deseas es que al obtener la fecha se quiten esas diagonales, puedes hacer uso de la función `REPLACE`:

```
REPLACE(CampoFecha, '/', '')
```

Aquí puedes ver la <kbd>[demostración de la solución](http://rextester.com/NIKVO13820)</kbd>.